# Selected filename of downloading file is not directly editable

Tags: nautilus, filename

Every time I download a file in Ubuntu 21.10 with **Chrome 100**, the nautilus windows opens with the filename selected (highlighted in orange), but the filename is not directly editable. I have to click on the filename to edit it. In the past, it was directly editable, and it makes no sense it to be selected if it is not editable. It happens, for example, if I right click on the image below and choose to download it.

[image: screen capture of nautilus]

I have followed your advice and I can confirm that Firefox 98 does not have this problem, but Opera 84 does.

Is there any option to set in order to make it editable?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on 21.10. Can you give more details on when this happens, i.e., from which programs are you opening the dialog: a browser? Firefox? Chrome? Provide stepwise instructions so someone can exactly reproduce what you do.

Comment: This is because something else was selected in nautilus. This happens for me in 20.04  when I choose the folder to download, but it's still selected.

Comment: Same problem with chrome on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS